# Solve $x^2f''(x)+f(x)=0$ check my answer

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, proof-verification

I'd just like someone else to review my answer, I'm  preparing for an exam and I saw this question but a solution was not included with it, and the result is...somewhat unpleasant, It's not feasible to derive it twice and check that it is indeed a solution.

Ok, so the question is to solve the ODE $x^2f''(x)+f(x)=0$, it's not with constant coefficients so there is no set method, but we do have a hint: define $t=\ln{x}$

Ok, so $e^{2t}f''(e^t)+f(e^t)=0$ is what we want to solve. Let's look at the function $g(t)=f(e^t)$:

$g'(t)=e^tf'(e^t)$, and $g''(t)=e^tf'(e^t)+e^{2t}f''(e^t)$

We can see that $g''(t)-g'(t)+g(t)=e^{2t}f''(t)+f(e^t)$.

So solving $g''(t)-g'(t)+g(t)=0$ is equivalent to solving our original question.

Using the method of finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial, the solutions are $g_1(t)=e^{\frac{1}{2}t}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)$ and $g_2(t)=e^{\frac{1}{2}t}\sin({\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t})$

And the most general solution is $g(t)=f(e^t)=c_1e^{\frac{1}{2}t}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)+c_2e^{\frac{1}{2}t}\sin({\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t}) $

But since our original question was in the sense of $x$, not $t$, our final answer should be $f(x)=c_1e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln x}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\ln x)+c_2e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln x}\sin({\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\ln x})$

Is this result correct?

Comment: You can simplify $e^{1/2 ln(x)}=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: That's the thing, it's not a very pleasant solution to check. it has trigonometric functions with logarithms inside them, at least for me it's not feasible to check it, and even if i did i wouldnt be 100% sure i derived correctly. that doesnt simplify a lot :D

Comment: It's not pleasant, but it's not exactly impossible either.

Comment: Use the hint given by @sonystarmap, use the product rule, use the chain rule  $(\cos(\ln x))' = -\dfrac{\sin(\ln x)}{x}$, etc.

Comment: matlab seems to agree with my answer, i guess that's good enough for me. also im more concerned about the logic in the proof, rather than if i made an arithmetic error somewhere like i always do

Comment: Your solution looks OK. The simplification suggested by @sonystarmap seems natural, but that is more or less the only remark I have.

Comment: you can see some details about this solution in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Comment: It seems that the question coule be answered trivially with Mathematica or Maple. For questions of a similar nature, it is usually better to try that first, and only ask if the software is unable to handle a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Direct solution check](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2*f%27%27%5Bx%5D%20%2B%20f%5Bx%5D%20%3D%3D%200)  using the free Wolfram Alpha seems to match

Answer (score 0):

Define
\begin{align}
g(x) = \sqrt{x} \sin(r \log(x))
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
g'(x) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \sin(r \log(x))
+ \sqrt{x}\cos(r\log(x)) \cdot\frac{r}{x}
\\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(\sin(r\log(x))+ 2r\cos(r\log(x))
\end{align}
Differentiating again (note, that we already know the derivatives of $\sin(\log(x))$ and $\cos(\log(x))$ from before). Note, that $r=\sqrt{3}$ and later I replace $w=r\log(x)$.
\begin{align}
g''(x)&=\frac{-1}{4\sqrt{x}^3}(\sin(r\log(x))+ 2r\cos(r\log(x))
\\&\quad+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}
(\cos(r\log(x))\frac{r}{x}-\sin(\log(x))\frac{2r^2}{x}) 
\\
&=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x}^3}(
-\sin(w)
-2r\cos(w))+2r\cos(w)-4r^2sin(w))
\\&=
\frac{-1}{4\sqrt{x}^3}(1+r^2)\sin(w)\\
&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}^3}\sin(\sqrt{3}\log(x))
\\
&=
\frac{-1}{x^2}\sqrt{x} \sin(\sqrt{3}\log(x))
\end{align} 
Now, doing everything again for $h(x) = \sqrt{x} \cos(r \log(x))$ you will probably (left as exercise) obtain
\begin{align}
h''(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2}\sqrt{x} \cos(\sqrt{3} \log(x))
\end{align}
And as you can see,
\begin{align}
y(x) &= c_1 h(x)+c_2g(x) \\
\Rightarrow y''(x) &=c_1h''(x)+c_2g''(x) \\
&=\frac{-1}{x^2}(c_1 h(x)+c_2g(x))
\\
&=\frac{-1}{x^2} y(x) \\
\Leftrightarrow 
0&=y''(x)x^2+y(x)
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \blacksquare
\end{align}

Comment: @ sonystarmap: You wrote " $r=\sqrt{3}$", but your $r$ should be equal to $ \sqrt{3}/2.$

Comment: That is correct. My mistake. But sadly, I'm too tired to correct that mistake, sorry!

Comment: @ sonystarmap: It is interesting that the odetest command of Maple produces for your "solution" with $\sqrt{3}$ instead of $\sqrt{3}/2$ not $0$, but $$-9/4\,{\it \_C1}\,\sqrt {x}\sin \left( \sqrt {3}\ln  \left( x \right) 
 \right) -9/4\,{\it \_C2}\,\sqrt {x}\cos \left( \sqrt {3}\ln  \left( x
 \right)  \right) 
  .$$